# XSLT for extract a XML inside another XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, transformation

I'm development a XSLT for extract a XML encoded ISO-8859-1 inside another XML tag, but my XSLD work only XML encoded UTF-8.

See the example bellow:

My XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webservice/nfd"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns2="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws">
    <ns0:template match="/env:Envelope/env:Body/ns2:GerarNfseResponse/return">
        <ns0:value-of select="XML" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </ns0:template>
</ns0:stylesheet>
```

Inboud:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <env:Header></env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <ns2:GerarNfseResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws">
            <return>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;ISO-8859-1&quot; standalone=&quot;yes&quot;?&gt;
&lt;GerarNfseResposta xmlns=&quot;http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws&quot;&gt;
    &lt;ListaMensagemRetorno&gt;
        &lt;MensagemRetorno&gt;
            &lt;Codigo&gt;E189&lt;/Codigo&gt;
            &lt;Mensagem&gt;Arquivo enviado com erro de certificado. Certificado digital inválido.&lt;/Mensagem&gt;
            &lt;Correcao&gt;O solicitante do serviço de processamento do arquivo deve utilizar um certificado digital padrão ICP Brasil, não revogado e não expirado.&lt;/Correcao&gt;
        &lt;/MensagemRetorno&gt;
    &lt;/ListaMensagemRetorno&gt;
&lt;/GerarNfseResposta&gt;
            </return>
        </ns2:GerarNfseResponse>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Outbound (current)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Outbound (intended):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<GerarNfseResposta xmlns="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws">
    <ListaMensagemRetorno>
        <MensagemRetorno>
            <Codigo>E189</Codigo>
            <Mensagem>Arquivo enviado com erro de certificado. Certificado digital inválido.</Mensagem>
            <Correcao>O solicitante do serviço de processamento do arquivo deve utilizar um certificado digital padrão ICP Brasil, não revogado e não expirado.</Correcao>
        </MensagemRetorno>
    </ListaMensagemRetorno>
</GerarNfseResposta>
```

Any suggestion for solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `.` instead of `XML` e.g. `ns0:value-of select="."` or better

```
<ns0:output method="text"/>

<ns0:template match="/">
    <ns0:value-of select="env:Envelope/env:Body/ns2:GerarNfseResponse/return" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</ns0:template>
```